# Configuring rsnapshot to backup multiple computers - individual exclusion rules

Tags: backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I've got rsnapshot set up to backup two computers on my local network, as well as the server it's running on. How do I specify individual exclude sets for each backup? As it stands, I have individual cronjobs for each computer, each with its own rsnapshot.conf file. This would be fine, but I get three additional copies of hourly.* in my backup, which indicates that there is some redundancy going on in my setup. Do I have to write backup scripts for each one and have the excludes in there instead of in the main .conf file?

Comment: Are you saying that the server backup also backs up the backups from the other two machines? I can't quite work out what you're asking.

Comment: It backs up itself and two other machines over ssh.

Comment: Right, but where are the additional files, and what's creating them?

Comment: Oh I see. It excludes that mount.

Comment: It's still not obvious from your description what the problem is.

Comment: I've actually figured it out since. My issue was that I wasn't using one config file, rather I was using multiple rsnapshot jobs, one for each computer. This led to hourly.0 having the latest for one computer, but not both. I've since found out that when you set backup commands, you can set individual parameters (eg backup comp1 backupmnt exclude_file=foo). This setup allows me to do what I need from one config file.